# How to display date data in mysql inline on table blade laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm got confused for displaying date data inline on the table.

Mysql table is like this :

#### TABLE1

[image]

I want to display like this:

#### Tbl

[image]

How to display like that in MySQL Laravel?

Comment: Do you want to display the date in ``dd/mm/yyyy`` format in your PHP application?

Comment: No, i just want to display date data in horizontal order by name, when i foreach the date data it will display into vertical view.

Comment: Can you show what it looks like now?

Comment: i've already share the code in my answer sir

Answer (score 0):

This my blade code:

```
@foreach ($data_date as $key => $item)
    <tr>                     
       <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
       <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->date}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This my controller:

```
$data_date = DB::table('employees')  
                    ->rightJoin('schedules', 'employees.id', '=', 'schedules.employee_id')
                    ->get();
```

This the result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDSan.png)

Comment: so this is the result you wanted? this code works for what you wanted?  if not then this is not an answer and you should edit your question and add this to it